# I want to save a spreadsheet with a name from the contensts of a named range in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I searched "get save as filename from named range in another worksheet vba" and got no results.
I tried this:

```
Sub Save_Merge_file()
'
' Save_Merge_file Macro
'
    Windows("merge.csv").Activate
    Dim mfilename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\Users\e0300397\Documents\merges\"
    mfilename = Source.xlsx.Sheet1!filename
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & mfilename & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
End Sub
```

I get a "Runtime Error"
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put quotes " " around the mfilename statement...the part after the = anyway

Comment: Open the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and type ?mfilename after stepping past that line to see what you really assigned to it.

Comment: Rdster, the quotes eliminated the error but now the file name is Source.xlsx.Sheet1!filename.csv

Comment: Is this run from the Source workbook?

Comment: yes the range FileName in the Workbook named Source has the text I want in the new filename.

Comment: sorry no it is run from the new file that doesn't have a name yet

Comment: I think you need to flesh the contents of the question out more...How can you run the code from a new workbook with no name?  Is this in Personal.xlsb or something?

Comment: Sorry, the new workbook has a name but needs to be renamed everytime data is pulled from the source file.  and yes the macro is in a Personal xlsb  file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, that's what I get for only half reading...

Try this...

```
Sub Save_Merge_file()
  Dim sFileName As String, sPath As String
  Dim wbSource as Workbook

  Windows("Source.xlsx").Activate
  Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
  sPath = "C:\Users\e0300397\Documents\merges\"
  sFileName = wbSource.Range("filename")

  Windows("merge.csv").Activate
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath & sFileName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

End Sub
```

If being launched from Personal...then you will need to properly reference the Source workbook above to the actual file.

Comment: I agree I need to "reference the Source workbook" - how do I do that?

Comment: The same way you did with merge

Comment: I tried   Set wbSource = Windows("source.xlxs.Sheet1!FileName") but that didn't work.

Comment: Nope...that isn't the name of the source file is it?  Source.xlsx is

Comment: Sorry Dyslexia kicking in  - still didn't work though    Set wbSource = Windows("source.xlsx").Sheet1!filename    - I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: Then you either don't have the Source.xlsx workbook open, or it is named something other than Source.xlsx.  Like I have stated previously...you should really edit your question and flesh it out with more details rather than keep revealing small bits and pieces via the comments.